# C++ fraction operator overloading but main class not working

Tags: c++, methods, operator-overloading

I am new in C++ and I have a problem with operator overloading. I just implemented the functions in the header file. I have completed the class as well but I cant get my main class to work. it doesn't send any output.

Please help my code is:

The header file:

```
class Fraction{
{

private:
int numerator;
int denominator;
public:

Fraction (int a=1, int b=1);
//declare Mutators 
void setNumerator(int);
void setDenominator(int);

 //declare Accessors
int getNumerator();
int getDenominator();

 Fraction operator+(const Fraction &fra)const;
 Fraction operator-(const Fraction &fra)const;
 Fraction operator*(const Fraction &fra)const;
 Fraction operator/(const Fraction &fra)const;


};

#endif /* FRACTION_H */
```

The Fraction.cpp

```
Fraction:: Fraction (int a,int b)
{
while (a<b && b<0)
{
    if(b<0)
    {
        std:: cout<<"please enter a number grater then 0 in 
denominator";

    }
    else 
    {
        std:: cout<< "Please enter numerator greater then denominator";
    }

}
   numerator= a;
   denominator= b;
}
void Fraction::setNumerator(int a)
{
  numerator =a;
}

void Fraction::setDenominator(int a)
{
denominator =a;
}


// Operations

Fraction Fraction::operator-(const Fraction &f1)const
{
Fraction temp;
temp.numerator= (numerator*f1.denominator)-f1.numerator*denominator;
temp.denominator = denominator*f1.denominator;

for(int i = temp.numerator * temp.denominator ; i > 1; i--) //
{
    if((temp.numerator % i == 0) && (temp. % i == 0))
    {
        {
           temp.denominator  /= i;
            temp.numerator /= i;
        }

    }


}
return temp;

}


Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &f1)const
{
int a= (numerator*f1.denominator)+f1.numerator*denominator;
int b = denominator*f1.denominator;

for(int i = a * b ; i > 1; i--) //
{
    if((a % i == 0) && (b % i == 0))
    {
        {
            b /= i;
            a /= i;
        }

    }


}
return Fraction(a,b);
}

Fraction Fraction::operator*(const Fraction &f1)const
{
int a= numerator *f1.numerator;
int b= denominator*f1.denominator;

for(int i = a * b ; i > 1; i--) //
{
    if((a % i == 0) && (b % i == 0))
    {
        {
            b /= i;
            a /= i;
        }

    }


}
return Fraction(a,b);
}

Fraction Fraction::operator /(const Fraction& f1) const
{
int a= numerator *f1.denominator;
int b= denominator*f1.numerator;

for(int i = a * b ; i > 1; i--) //
{
    if((a % i == 0) && (b % i == 0))
    {
        {
            b /= i;
            a /= i;
        }

    }


}
return Fraction(a,b);
}



std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, Fraction const& data) {
out << data.getDenominator() << ':';
out << data.getNumerator() << ':';
return out;
}
```

My main class so far is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"



int main() {
 Fraction f1(1,2);
std:: cout<<f1.getDenominator();




return 0;
}
```

I tryed to see if i can write my main but i had no luck on getting it.

Comment: Where does `f1` come from in your main?

Comment: Hi I was trying to use the constructor. fo I tried Function f1(1,2);

Comment: I don't see it in your main.

Comment: Hi, I changed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see a `getDenominator` implementation in your code. Please post an complete and verifiable example...

Comment: hey, thanks that were the problem I got it fixed. thanks.